# Entity field representing a count with conditions

Tags: hibernate, jpa, count

I have an `@Entity Location` which has a field :

- `Set<Alert> openAlerts`

Then I have an `@Entity Alert` which has two fields :

- `AlertState state` which is an enum (can be `OPEN` or `CLOSED`)
- `Location originatedIn` which is the location where the alert originated.

At the moment in `Location` I have :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "originatedIn")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"originatedIn"})
private Set<Alert> openAlerts;
```

It retrieves all the alerts linked to the location (open or closed).

I want to replace that field with `Integer numberOpenAlerts`.
This new field should retrieve and count only the alerts linked to the location that have the `AlertState` of `OPEN`.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities that I can think of to start off with.

Since you are using Hibernate, you could use the `@Where` annotation on your `openAlerts` to limit this Set to Alerts that are open:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "originatedIn")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"originatedIn"})
@Where(clause="state='OPEN'")
private Set<Alert> openAlerts;
```

depending on what the `state` column actually contains corresponding to the `OPEN` enum value.

See [this question about @Where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700071/how-to-use-where-in-jpa-hibernate) for some pointers.

Alternatively, you could create a database view with the location details and the count of the open alerts. Then you would create another Entity corresponding to that view called something like `LocationWithOpenAlertCount`.

Finally, you could create a DTO for the Location plus count and create a JPQL query that does a [Constructor Select query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor) with the appropriate location fields and the open Alert count. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989315/how-to-use-constructor-mapping-with-spring-jpa-repositories/31060784#31060784) for an example.

Comment: I think the last solution will do it. Thanks for the tips